# Why Iterm2 takes time to show show the home director when I open it for the first time

Tags: xcode, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

I am using Item2 with zsh shell, When I open Item2  when I open Item it takes up to 10 seconds to show the home directory, and it shows a log about Xcode?

```
2022-05-10 18:02:50.016 xcodebuild[1075:8199] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionSentinelHostApplications for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionHosts.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
2022-05-10 18:02:50.017 xcodebuild[1075:8199] Requested but did not find extension point with identifier Xcode.IDEKit.ExtensionPointIdentifierToBundleIdentifier for extension Xcode.DebuggerFoundation.AppExtensionToBundleIdentifierMap.watchOS of plug-in com.apple.dt.IDEWatchSupportCore
```

[image]